# Is dynamic ASP.NET page data from database searchable by search engines?

Tags: asp.net, search, datagrid, seo, search-engine

I have an ASP.NET web app with an ASPX page that displays food item names and descriptions using a datagrid which I populate from a database during the OnPreRender event. The datagrid gets rendered as an HTML table. All of the data is automatically rendered. There are no query sting to parse.

Question:

Will the page be "crawled" so that the item names and descriptions are searchable from Google, etc.?

Comment: It doesn't matter *where* the HTML comes from - as long as it comes from a resource path (URL) that can be found/traversed and the HTTP results in something that is searchable. Dynamic (i.e. AJAX content) is a bit harder to deal with. In the case of ASP.NET WebControls the *complete HTML (already containing the data)* is usually returned and thus generally does not have to deal with said dynamic content ..

Comment: I'm sorry, but it sounds like you mean the data would usually be searchable, right?

Comment: Generally, yes. To see the raw result that a standard web-crawler sees, use [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) to GET the specified URL - alternatively, the "View Page Source" of browsers (which?) should often be correct; just make sure not to inspect the live DOM! The raw markup/content dumped (e.g. no JavaScript is executed) is what it can be crawled. Of course, this doesn't imply that all content is crawled the same way - and certain arrangements may be "better for SEO".

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is – yes it will be.

What you can to is to go to google webmaster tools and use Fetch as Google option to see what Google will see when your page is accessed.

Just make sure that you always show the same content for the same URL. Google doesn’t like it when you show different content to different visitors using the same URL.